# How do I add authentication to the OpenTest UI and API

Tags: opentest

I'd like to expand my use of OpenTest and having authentication required to gain access to the UI as well as the Rest API would likely be required for me to get this request approved internally. What are my options?

Comment: Part of this functionality can be achieved with a reverse proxy like [Traefik](https://containo.us/traefik/) or [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/). It's fairly easy to put the OpenTest server behind a Traefik middleware that requires basic authentication. However, there is still one missing piece: the test actors don't know how to authenticate to the server, currently. This functionality is being added and I'll post a complete answer to this question once this feature is released.

Answer (score 0):

The authentication feature was introduced with version 1.2.1. To activate it, you must set the `adminLogin` and `adminPassword` parameters in `server.yaml`:

**server.yaml**

```yaml
# ...

adminLogin: admin
adminPassword: h!Kr8qUx

# ...
```

Of course, you must also configure the test actors so they authenticate with the server. To do that, you must set the `serverLogin` and `serverPassword` parameters in `actor.yaml`:

**actor.yaml**

```yaml
# ...

syncServerUrl: http://localhost:3000
serverLogin: admin
serverPassword: h!Kr8qUx

# ...
```